# Can't install PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm unable to install PIL. When I run `pip install PIL` I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpWJojCu
```

I've tried following the answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil) question but I get the same error.

Stack: Python 2.7, PIP, EC2 Ubuntu machine.

Comment: `pip install pillow`

Comment: See previous comment: use [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) instead of outdated PIP. Also, your debug log is stored in `/tmp/tmpWJojCu`, so read that: it should give you more information on what went wrong.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This one bites a lot of people, `PIL` has become [`pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow).

```
pip install pillow
```

But the import name was unchanged, so it is different from the package name now.  That is, you continue to use:

```
from PIL import Image
```