# How to add a google image to a chart using plotly library?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['Sensor', 'Atuador', 'Arduino'],
                             'Total': [55, 45, 5]})
```

I need to build a pie chart for the types of electronic components I am using in a project. So I used plotly as follows:

```
fig = px.pie(df, values='Total', names='Type')

# Add image
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cldougl/plot_images/add_r_img/vox.png",
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x=1, y=1.05,
    xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"
    )
)

# Add title
fig.update_layout(title={'text':"Add Title <br> Add Subtitle",
                               'y' : 0.97, 'x': 0.5,
                               'xanchor': 'center',
                               'yanchor': 'top'})

fig.show()
```

This code is working perfectly, to build it I relied on: https://plotly.com/python/images/

However, when adding an image along the plotly plot, there is a problem. The example image appears on my graph, but when I try to switch to an Arduino logo image (available on google) the image does not appear on the graph. How can I solve?

```
fig = px.pie(df, values='Total', names='Type')

# Add image
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
           #source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cldougl/plot_images/add_r_img/vox.png",
            source="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/117-1179524_icon-arduino-arduino- 
    logo.png", # My image
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x=1, y=1.05,
    sizex=0.2, sizey=0.2,
    xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"
    )
)

# Add title
fig.update_layout(title={'text':"Add Title <br> Add Subtitle",
    'y' : 0.97, 'x': 0.5,
    'xanchor': 'center',
    'yanchor': 'top'})

fig.show()
```

Comment: Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I managed to solve it like this:
pip install Pillow==9.0.0
form PIL import Image
import requests

url='https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/117-1179524_icon-arduino-arduino- 
    logo.png'
im = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
now just do: source=im,