# Plotly HTML export with embedded image

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to embed an image (logo) in a Plotly plot and then export it to HTML, keeping the logo in the image. I've run into some weird behavior.

If I do it like this

```py
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,4,8,2]
fig = px.scatter(x,y)
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cldougl/plot_images/add_r_img/vox.png",
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0.5, y=0.5,
        sizex=0.4, sizey=0.4,
        xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"
    )
)
fig.write_html('test.html')
```

it exports just fine and the image appears in the exported html.

If instead I use a local image:

```py
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,4,8,2]
fig = px.scatter(x,y)
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source='vox.png',
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0.5, y=0.5,
        sizex=0.4, sizey=0.4,
        xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"
    )
)
fig.write_html('test.html')
```

The exported HTML does not include the image (but the figure in Jupyter notebook does!).

If I look at the resulting HTML, it looks like it embeds the image as base64:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQMAAADCCAYAAABNEq...Z0DbwjH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=`
Shouldn't it be able to do that with a local image without an issue?

Additionally if I use a different URL that I host that works just fine from a browser, the image doesn't appear at all (Jupyter or HTML), but there are no exceptions thrown. It just silently fails.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66178993/16733101

Comment: @Chebyshev since that answer solved your problem, i'm voting to close this question as a duplicate. people don't look in comments often, so marking this question as a duplicate will help others with the same question as you get directed to the right place. cheers!